# HTTPConnection Not Returning Redirected Page

Tags: jsp, redirect, response, httpconnection

I have a JSP page that performs some function and will redirect to success page if all goes well.  If there is an error the page continues and displays the error information.  I’m writing a test to drive the page but the response from the server is always the error information weather or not the function worked.  The page is redirected and works properly from a browser.  I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 8.

I’ve tried adding a response.flushBuffer() and  response.reset() before the redirect to no avail.

This is the JSP page:

```
<%
    boolean success = performFunction();
    if (success)
    {
        response.sendRedirect(“SuccessPage”);
        return;
    }
%>

<html>
<h1>There was an error</h1>
<html>
```

This is the code that I use to post to the page:

```
    StringBuffer pageResp = new StringBuffer();

    // Setup a URL object
    URL url = new URL(urlString);


    // Open a connection to the URL
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);


    // Complete the request by getting the input stream
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
    int len = 0;
    char[] buf = new char[2048];
    while ((len=is.read(buf,0,2048)) != -1)
        pageResp.append(new String(buf).substring(0, len));

    is.close();

    System.out.print(pageResp.toString());
```

Comment: How are you calling JSP ?

Comment: Though an application level bean.  The function is invoked and results returned correctly.

Comment: I can eliminate the function call and just do a redirect when the page opens and that will return the error message.